# mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

Tags: android-studio

i am building an app which shows current location but i got an error for :

```
 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

and

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

I got cannot resolve symbol error.
As i am new to android i am not able to get this.

```
Module:app =
             dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Update your Gradel with latest Gradel com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0.

Comment: already done that, not working it says "failed to resolve".